# Attaching old archive table (_h) back to original feature class on re-enabling geodatabase archiving?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, enterprise-geodatabase, archiving

I'm trying to figure out a way to update the schema of an archived feature class. There was a lot of discussion about this from 2012 and prior. https://geonet.esri.com/message/115340#115340 < -- This discussion in particular. Following the links in this discussion led to quite a few work-arounds, but all of them in 9.3 or 10.0. I'm working in 10.2.2. Has this issue been resolved and I'm just missing something? Is there a simple way to do this now? It is also worth mentioning that my organization does not use versions.

In the referenced discussion above, someone from ESRI mentions that "There is currently an enhancement request in our system to implement this functionality: NIM050307 - Option to attach the old archive table (_h) back to the original feature class on re-enabling archiving." Was this done?

I found this post,  Restoring Geodatabase History | Geodatabase Geek, and they have was seems to be the most reliable work-around. A python script they created is mentioned, but apparently no way to do this entirely in python, even in 10.1. The enabling and disabling of the archive must be done in Arc.

Overall, my question is, has there been an update to do this process easily? I will have to do this from time to time and would like to maintain the archive tables as I work in the fire industry and fire history is extremely important.